# Jest Unit Tests do not work started with WebStorm Jest Testrunner

Tags: angular, jestjs, webstorm, nrwl-nx

I am using WebStorm 2019.2, Angular 8 and latest nrwl monorepo.  When starting Angular test with `ng test <app-name>` all works well.  If I try to run tests from within WebStorm (by clicking the green triangle in the editor) I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed: "Zone is needed for the async() test helper but could not be found.
Please make sure that your environment includes zone.js/dist/zone.js"
```

I tried hours googeling to find a solution for that problem but was not successful.  Any idea how to solve that problem?

PS: The monorepo also hosts a NestJS server.  Running single test from within WebStorm works well for the NestJS app.

Comment: see https://github.com/nrwl/nx/pull/1467#issuecomment-506973401 - does it make things any better?

Comment: @lena:  Thanks a lot!!! That solved the problem. Could you make an answer out of your comment so that I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try a workaround from https://github.com/nrwl/nx/pull/1467#issuecomment-506973401:

1. Add the following jest config to the *package.json* and adjust where necessary:

```
 "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/apps/nx-jest-example/src/test-setup.ts"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/",
      "<rootDir>/dist/",
      "<rootDir>/src/test.ts",
      "<rootDir>/apps/nx-jest-example-e2e/"
    ],
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "diagnostics": false,
        "tsConfig": "<rootDir>/apps/nx-jest-example/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "stringifyContentPathRegex": "\\.html$",
        "astTransformers": [
          "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-preset-angular/InlineHtmlStripStylesTransformer"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

2. Change the configuration in the *Edit Configurations* to use the *package.json* instead of the *jest.config*